# Displaying data retrieved from json in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I am beginner webdeveloper. I use in my project Laravel 8 and Vue.

I have this code:

```
<template>
    <div class="sm:bg-transparent pt-6 md:mt-16 w-full px-4 md:px-0">
        <h1 class="text-dark text-4xl sm:text-3xl font-medium sm:text-center mb-6">{{ __('Archiwum') }}</h1>


        <preloader
            v-if="isLoadingInProgress"
            class="py-8"
            :class="preloaderClass"
        />

        <div class="text-center" v-if="gasmeters.length == 0 && !isLoadingInProgress">
            {{ __('Nie posiadasz jeszcze żadnych odczytów') }}
        </div>

        <div v-if="gasmeters.length">
            <div class="bg-white rounded border border-stroke flex items-start p-6"
                 v-for="(gasmeter, index) in gasmeters"
                 v-bind:key="`gasmeter-${index}`">
                <div class="mr-6">
                    <img class="mb-2" :src="gasmeters.img"/> {{ gasmeters }}
                </div>
                <div class="w-1/5">
                    <span class="font-bold text-xl text-grey">Lipiec 2020 (#123)</span>
                </div>
                <div class="w-1/5">
                    <span class="font-bold text-xl text-grey">Stan:</span> <span>2120</span>
                </div>
                <div class="w-1/5">
                    <span class="font-bold text-xl text-grey">Data:</span> <span>2020.01.12</span>
                </div>
                <div class="w-1/5">
                    <span class="text-xl">Zgłoszone przez aplikację</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


    </div>
</template>
<script>
import axios from "axios";
import Preloader from "@/common/components/Preloader";

export default {
    components: {
        Preloader
    },
    mounted() {
        this.loadGasmeters();
    },
    data() {
        return {
            gasmeters: [],
            isLoadingInProgress: false,
        }
    },
    computed: {
        preloaderClass() {
            return this.gasmeters.length > 0
                ? ""
                : "loading--transparent loading--block";
        }
    },
    methods: {
        loadGasmeters() {
            this.isLoadingInProgress = true;

            axios
                .get(route('api.archive.list'))
                .then(response => {
                    this.gasmeters = _.get(response, "data.data", []);
                    console.log(this.gasmeters);
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log(error);
                })
                .then(() => {
                    this.isLoadingInProgress = false;
                });
        },

    }
}
</script>
```

My php return me:

```
{
    "data": [
        [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "value": "99.00",
                "settlement_date": "2020-10-20T22:00:00.000000Z",
                "loaded_from": "Stan pobrany z systemu BAŁTYKGAZ",
                "img": "img/icons/crm.svg",
                "created_at": "2020-10-21T15:09:22.000000Z"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "value": "109.00",
                "settlement_date": "2020-10-20T22:00:00.000000Z",
                "loaded_from": "Zgłoszone przez aplikację",
                "img": "img/icons/cms.svg",
                "created_at": "2020-10-21T17:02:18.000000Z"
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

I have problem with my part this code:

```
<div v-if="gasmeters.length">
            <div class="bg-white rounded border border-stroke flex items-start p-6"
                 v-for="(gasmeter, index) in gasmeters"
                 v-bind:key="`gasmeter-${index}`">
                <div class="mr-6">
                    <img class="mb-2" :src="gasmeters.img"/> {{ gasmeters }}
                </div>
                <div class="w-1/5">
                    <span class="font-bold text-xl text-grey">Lipiec 2020 (#123)</span>
                </div>
                <div class="w-1/5">
                    <span class="font-bold text-xl text-grey">Stan:</span> <span>2120</span>
                </div>
                <div class="w-1/5">
                    <span class="font-bold text-xl text-grey">Data:</span> <span>2020.01.12</span>
                </div>
                <div class="w-1/5">
                    <span class="text-xl">Zgłoszone przez aplikację</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I want replace my img by img from json, "Lipiec 2020 (#123)" => gasmeters.settlement_date (# gasmeters.id), "Stan: " 2120 => Stan: gasmeters.value

How can I make it?

This: {{ gasmeters }} return me:

```
[ [ { "id": 1, "value": "99.00", "settlement_date": "2020-10-20T22:00:00.000000Z", "loaded_from": "Stan pobrany z systemu BAŁTYKGAZ", "img": "img/icons/crm.svg", "created_at": "2020-10-21T15:09:22.000000Z" }, { "id": 2, "value": "109.00", "settlement_date": "2020-10-20T22:00:00.000000Z", "loaded_from": "Zgłoszone przez aplikację", "img": "img/icons/cms.svg", "created_at": "2020-10-21T17:02:18.000000Z" } ] ]
```

Please help me

Comment: try `<img class="mb-2" :src="gasmeter.img"/> {{ gasmeter.img }}`

Comment: it's not working :(

Comment: then add code of php which return that json you need to fix that side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I saw Your problem. Because your response data from service API Laravel is the array in array. If you want to get your right data, you can do in 2 way:

- You change the front end data when get from service API, like this:

```
    axios.get(route('api.archive.list'))
            .then(response => {
                this.gasmeters = _.get(response, "data.data[0]", []);
                console.log(this.gasmeters);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            })
            .then(() => {
                this.isLoadingInProgress = false;
            });
```

[image]

- Or you can change the Laravel API like this:

```
    {
        "data": [{
                    "id": 1,
                    "value": "99.00",
                    "settlement_date": "2020-10-20T22:00:00.000000Z",
                    "loaded_from": "Stan pobrany z systemu BAŁTYKGAZ",
                    "img": "img/icons/crm.svg",
                    "created_at": "2020-10-21T15:09:22.000000Z"
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "value": "109.00",
                    "settlement_date": "2020-10-20T22:00:00.000000Z",
                    "loaded_from": "Zgłoszone przez aplikację",
                    "img": "img/icons/cms.svg",
                    "created_at": "2020-10-21T17:02:18.000000Z"
                }
            ]
    }
```

[image]